# Hibernate java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction cannot be cast to org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction

Tags: hibernate, flush, classcastexception, entitymanager

I'm using Hibernate with an EntityManager. When I use

```
    Session session = (Session)entityManager.getDelegate();  
    session.flush();
    session.clear();
```

I get

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction cannot be cast to org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue$InsertActionSorter.sort(ActionQueue.java:636)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.sortInsertActions(ActionQueue.java:369)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.sortActions(ActionQueue.java:355)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:224)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:99)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
```

Since it doesn't say which entity causes the problem, I'm stuck here. Does anyone have an idea what can cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in Hibernate. Exception is thrown when following conditions are met:

- id generation strategy is `identity`
- entity is saved outside of transaction
- `hibernate.order_inserts` is `true`

It happens because `EntityIdentityInsertAction` can be added to the `ActionQueue.insertions` list, whereas `ActionQueue$InsertActionSorter` expects that it contains only `EntityInsertAction`s.

It looks like this bug was not reported yet, so [feel free to report it](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH).

Perhaps you can change the value of `hibernate.order_inserts` as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error just because I forget to add `@Transactional` annotation on the method that calls `em.persist(myNewEntity)` as I thought all the callers will be on Transaction,

the error is not popping directly but when I tried to delete all rows from a table

really the error is misleading but its the same as the second case in [@axtavt answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7414152/4251431)

so

> make sure that save operation is done within an active transaction